# jquery: simulating a click via jquery - not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

so I have a very simple code

```js
    $("#toggle_google").trigger("click");
    $("#toggle_google").click();
    
    $("[id^='toggle_']").on("click", function() {
     console.log("clicked: " + $(this).attr("id").replace("toggle_", "").toString());
                    
      return false;
    });
    
    $("#toggle_google").on("click", function() {
     console.log("clicked toggle_google");
        
        return false;
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
      <a href="www.google.com" id="toggle_google">Google</a>
      <br>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="toggle_bing">Bing</a>
    </p>
```

I don't get anything on my console when the page loads. If I click on the links, I get messages on my console.

I've come up with my code after reading various discussions in stackoverflow and also reading jquery.com

Any ideas why it isn't working?

Here's a jsfiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/4cxkw4c6/24/)

Comment: You are triggering the click before you have added the onclick event listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined your click event after calling , so just revers it. and it will work fine.

```
$("[id^='toggle_']").on("click", function() {
    console.log("clicked: " + $(this).attr("id").replace("toggle_", "").toString());

});

$("#toggle_google").on("click", function() {
    console.log("clicked google");
});

$("#toggle_google").trigger("click");
$("#toggle_google").click();
```

[**LiNK**](https://jsfiddle.net/4cxkw4c6/34/)